# SQL (Server) XML cast question - Error XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to access XML data attributes that are in an Navchar column

A column with data:

```
<Summary><Item><Name>Test22</Name><Value>3.50</Value></Item></Summary>

A column without data:
</Summary>
```

Name is Discount Name and Value is Discount Value

This information comes from an OrderItem table stored on SQL Server

I try this query to extract Order Information from the COM_OrderItem table

```
SELECT OrderID AS [Order No], OrderItemUnitCount As [Units], OrderItemSKUName As [Product], OrderItemUnitPrice As [Unit Price], OrderItemTotalPrice As [Line Total],
CAST(OrderItemProductDiscounts as XML) As CatDiscounts, Child.discountName AS [DiscountName], Child.discountValue AS [DiscountValue],
FROM COM_OrderItem

CROSS APPLY
 
(
 
       SELECT Summary.c.value('Name[1]','varchar(max)') AS discountName
 
       ,Summary.c.value('Value[1]','decimal(18,2)') AS discountValue
 
       FROM CatDiscounts.nodes('/Summary/Item') Summary (c)
 
) Child
```

I get the following error:

Child Caused exception: Invalid column name 'CatDiscounts'. The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

It seems the CatDiscounts column name is the problem.

However, I am not sure how to change the query to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated (am a newbie at SQL).

Tried many different combinations of the above code

Tried using SET on the CatDiscounts column name and got syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the column to XML and then to apply .nodes() function.

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT OrderID AS [Order No]
         , OrderItemUnitCount As [Units]
         , OrderItemSKUName As [Product]
         , OrderItemUnitPrice As [Unit Price]
         , OrderItemTotalPrice As [Line Total]
         ,CAST(OrderItemProductDiscounts as XML) As CatDiscounts
         , Child.discountName AS [DiscountName]
         , Child.discountValue AS [DiscountValue]
    FROM COM_OrderItem
)

SELECT OrderID AS [Order No]
     , OrderItemUnitCount As [Units]
     , OrderItemSKUName As [Product]
     , OrderItemUnitPrice As [Unit Price]
     , OrderItemTotalPrice As [Line Total]
     , CatDiscounts As [CatDiscounts]
     , Child.discountName AS [DiscountName]
     , Child.discountValue AS [DiscountValue]
FROM DataSource
CROSS APPLY
(
       SELECT Summary.c.value('Name[1]','varchar(max)') AS discountName
       ,Summary.c.value('Value[1]','decimal(18,2)') AS discountValue
 
       FROM CatDiscounts.nodes('/Summary/Item') Summary (c)
 
) Child;
```

If you look at [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) you can see that the `FROM`, `JOIN` (and cross apply) are executed before the `SELECT` statement.

So, you are converting the `OrderItemProductDiscounts` to XML in the `SELECT` but in the `CROSS APPLY` it is still not converted and .nodes function cannot be applied.